# Cannot store results from identify

Tags: r

I want to store the results from my click with `identify` on my plot. The issue I am having is that the interaction with the plot is not from `identify` but all plots are plotted. However, I have found that sometimes identify will work but most times it will not, how can I correctly implement `identify` within my function and store the results as a vector?

```
some_func <- function(data, response, predictors, label){
  form <- reformulate(predictors, response=response)
  mod <- lm(form, data)
  dfb_mod <- dfbeta(mod)[,-1] %>% data.frame() %>% as.list()
  par(mfrow=c(2, 2))
  xlabel <- names(dfb_mod)
  ident_labels <- data[, label]
  #return(ident_labels)
  a <- mapply(function(x, y)plot(x, xlab=y, ylab='response') %>% with(abline(h=0)) %>% with(identify(., names=ident_labels)), dfb_mod, xlabel)
  return(a)
}

require(faraway)
data(savings)
savings2 <- savings %>% rownames_to_column()
some_func(savings2, 'sr', c('pop15', 'pop75', 'dpi', 'ddpi'), 'rowname')
```

Comment: There is no `rowname` column in `savings`.  There is no return value for the `plot`; `out <- plot(dfb_mod[[1]], xlab = xlabel[1], ylab = 'response')#
> out#
NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your piping of the plotting functions doesn't make much sense. Write your `mapply` like this:

```
  a <- mapply(
    function(x, y) {
      plot(x, xlab=y, ylab='response') 
      abline(h=0)
      identify(x, labels = ident_labels)
    }, 
    dfb_mod, xlabel
  )
```

Now it should work.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed, you have my thanks! Why did my approach not work effectly? I had thought by including `with` things should run smoothly (as they have done in the past with `mapply` plotting`.

Comment: No sure where you got that from, I think you are misunderstanding what pipes do and what they are used for. The piping paradigm requires that something is being piped, usually a data.frame goes from one function to the next. But functions like `plot` and `abline` return `NULL` invisibly. So e.g. your function calls will become `with(NULL, abline(h=0))` (which is still ok), and then `with(NULL, identify(., names=ident_labels))`, which means that `identify` just gets labels but no data.

Comment: Oh I see, actually this explains what I did in the past. Because essentially I had piped with `mtext` and `abline`, where `NULL` would not matter because data was not needed.

Comment: Alright, but there is no point to piping then, just use `mtext(....); abline(....)`.